# Synchronization between AOT and DB - Will I lose data?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I am new to AX 2009. I am adding a new field to the Tax 1099 tab for vendors to store additional info. I created a new extended type that is a 9 char. string. When I create a new string field on the VendTable the default length is 10. I then change it to use my extended type (9 chars in length). When I try to save the changes I get the text that says "...could result in data truncation". I know that is fine because this is a new field and there is no data in the db yet.

**BUT** - I also get the message "The action you have taken will drop and re-create the table VENDTABLE and all associated index. This can be caused by renaming a field or changing the type and/or size of the field."

It's unclear to me if it is ok for me to continue. If I continue will I loose all the data in my VENDTABLE or will the data be re-created along with the table?

I've read the information [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/daxis/archive/2009/04/26/synchronization-enhancements-in-dynamics-ax-2009.aspx) but I'm still unsure if I will loose my VENDTABLE data or not if I continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system will create a new table with the new field size, copy all the data from vendtable to the new table (truncating data in your 1099 field), then delete vendtable and rename the new table to vendtable.